# Couldn't replace symbol with '\w'

Tags: python, regex, replace, python-re, backslash

I've need to create regular expression using existing pattern. In my task user enters filename and pattern, my function should return `True` in case they are compatible and `False` if not.

For example, if `filename='log1.txt'`, and `pattern='log?.txt'` it should return `True`.

So I tried to use new variable and replace method (`PT = pattern.replace('?', '\w')`) to collect needed RE and return `bool(re.fullmatch(pt, filename))` after that, but replace method gives me `'\\w'` instead `'\w'`. I tried several ways but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

it shows double `\\` because your replace value having a symbol `\` so when you call the PT object that shows double `\\` one for your input one for indicating symbol if you don't want to see double `\\` then simply use print command that can print only single `\` which you want to include.

```
pattern='log?.txt'


PT = pattern.replace('?', '\w')

print(PT)

log\w.txt
```

If you want to match filename and pattern. Try this.

```
import re      

filename='log1.txt'
pattern='log?.txt'

def unix_match(filename: str, pattern: str) -> bool:
      pt = re.sub('\[.*\] ', '', pattern)      
      filename = re.sub('[1-9]', '', filename)
  
      return bool(re.fullmatch(pt, filename))
  
unix_match(filename,pattern)
```